# Did not find expected key while parsing a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to test my application and I continually get the following error:
the same error appear on all the test.

```
Error:
LocationsControllerTest#test_test_new:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: a YAML error occurred parsing       
/home/ubuntu/workspace/final_project/test/fixtures/admins.yml. Please note    
that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed.    
Please have a look at http://www.yaml.org/faq.html
The exact error was:
Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a    
block mapping at line 7 column 1
```

Below is the full trace of the error when I run the command: rails  fixtures:check_format

```
 rails aborted!
 Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a    
 block mapping at line 7 column 1
 /home/ubuntu/workspace/final_project/lib/tasks/fixtures.rake:16:in `block    
 (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 /home/ubuntu/workspace/final_project/lib/tasks/fixtures.rake:15:in `each'
 /home/ubuntu/workspace/final_project/lib/tasks/fixtures.rake:15:in `block   
 (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-   
  5.0.5/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:14:in `block in run_rake_task'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-   
 5.0.5/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:11:in `run_rake_task'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-   
 5.0.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `run_command!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-    
 5.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
 /home/ubuntu/workspace/final_project/bin/rails:9:in `require'
 /home/ubuntu/workspace/final_project/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-    
 2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-   
 2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-   
 2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in   
`run'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top    
 (required)>'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-   
 2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-   
 2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
 /home/ubuntu/workspace/final_project/bin/spring:15:in `require'
 /home/ubuntu/workspace/final_project/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
 bin/rails:3:in `load'
 bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
 Tasks: TOP => fixtures:check_format
 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What's in your test/fixtures/admins.yml?

Comment: as @SebastiánPalma says, without the contents of text/fixtures/admins.yml no one can tell you more than the error message already has

Comment: This  is what is in my admin.yml 

one: {}
 column: value
#
two: {}
column: value

Answer (score 0):

This is the default content in fixture yml file

```
one: {}
# column: value
two: {}
# column: value
```

Possibilities are you might have changed something it. Tabs are not allowed in it. 
You can remove all the content from this file and put above two lines again using space. And try again to run.